# Unable to click on pop up certificate while accessing website using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, pywin32

[image: This is the pop up certificate which I need to click 'ok'.]I am trying to go to a website automatically using selenium and python. The website has a certificate authentication system where I have to click 'OK' to enter the website. I am unable to click on the OK button there.

I have tried several things like *pyrobot*, *autoit*, *pyautogui* etc, but I am unable to click the ok button. The cursor doesn't move when I try to open this particular website.

Here is a sample code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import pyautogui

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("URL")
pyautogui.click(x=870, y=450, button='left')
```

Comment: It'll be hard to answer probably without seeing the certificate pop up you are getting. Is it an alert? I'd recommend you to update the question and add HTML (or the screenshot of the pop up) at least.

Answer (score 2):

This can be handled via threading:

```
import time
import threading
from selenium import webdriver
import win32com.client
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")

driver =webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")

def manage_os_popup():
   time.sleep(2)
   shell.SendKeys("{ENTER}", 0)
              
my_thread = threading.Thread(target = manage_os_popup)
my_thread.start()

driver.get("URL")
time.sleep(2)
```

`

Comment: Keep in mind that a certificate can be malicious code instead of a real certificate. How are you takings steps to check and prevent such event?

Comment: I  have no idea, but would be nice to know. :)

Comment: You need to be able to scan the certificate. The GUI normally has an option to inspect the certificate manually. That hook can be used to retrieve and check automatically the content inside a sandbox area.

Answer (score 0):

*I don't think Selenium can handle that, use [Win32com](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/) With sendkeys (Python/Pywin32 uses WScript from Windows Scripting Host) to control applications via shortcuts. eg.*

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
import win32com.client
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("URL")
time.sleep(2)
shell.SendKeys("{ENTER}", 0)
```

---

*[Here is a list of WScript-commands:](https://win32com.goermezer.de/microsoft/windows/controlling-applications-via-sendkeys.html)*

```
+----------------+------------------------------+
|      Key       |           Argument           |
+----------------+------------------------------+
| BACKSPACE      | {BACKSPACE}, {BS}, or {BKSP} |
| BREAK          | {BREAK}                      |
| CAPS LOCK      | {CAPSLOCK}                   |
| DEL or DELETE  | {DELETE} or {DEL}            |
| DOWN ARROW     | {DOWN}                       |
| END            | {END}                        |
| ENTER          | {ENTER} or ~                 |
| ESC            | {ESC}                        |
| HELP           | {HELP}                       |
| HOME           | {HOME}                       |
| INS or INSERT  | {INSERT} or {INS}            |
| LEFT ARROW     | {LEFT}                       |
| NUM LOCK       | {NUMLOCK}                    |
| PAGE DOWN      | {PGDN}                       |
| PAGE UP        | {PGUP}                       |
| PRINT SCREEN   | {PRTSC}                      |
| RIGHT ARROW    | {RIGHT}                      |
| SCROLL LOCK    | {SCROLLLOCK}                 |
| TAB            | {TAB}                        |
| UP ARROW       | {UP}                         |
| F1             | {F1}                         |
| F2             | {F2}                         |
| F3             | {F3}                         |
| F4             | {F4}                         |
| F5             | {F5}                         |
| F6             | {F6}                         |
| F7             | {F7}                         |
| F8             | {F8}                         |
| F9             | {F9}                         |
| F10            | {F10}                        |
| F11            | {F11}                        |
| F12            | {F12}                        |
| F13            | {F13}                        |
| F14            | {F14}                        |
| F15            | {F15}                        |
| F16            | {F16}                        |
+----------------+------------------------------+
```

Comment: No, still not working. It is not accepting the certificate.

Comment: Please check the post now.

Comment: @AmitDas when the pop up comes up, if you hit enter on keyboard - does it accept?