# Selenium Auto-click Certificate Pop-up not working in batch file

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, certificate

I'm working on a Python web-scrape script, where a certificate is required.  I have the same requirements as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60965147/unable-to-click-on-pop-up-certificate-while-accessing-website-using-selenium-and).

I am successfully using the code from the first Answer - it works great when I manually run it at a command prompt (Windows Server).

However, if I try to run the Python script in a batch file or a Powershell script, then have a Scheduled Task run it, then it always fails, with the certificate prompt still sitting there after the task runs. I've tried Windows Task Scheduler and other 3rd-party schedulers, with the same result. I don't believe it's a permission issue.

Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it?